# Dynamic reactive forms with pre-populated array values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have json file that has array of organizations and each organization object has its properties and array of regions as well. I am building reactive angular form with pre-populated values in it as shown below.

```
public createForm() {
  this.editForm = this.fb.group({
   organizations: this.fb.array(
     [this.buildOrganization('text')]
   )
  });
 }

 buildOrganization(name: String) {
    return new FormGroup({
      organizationTitle: new FormControl(name),
      regions: this.fb.array(
        [this.buildRegion()]
      )
    })
 }

 buildRegion() {
    return new FormGroup({
      regionTitle: new FormControl(''),
    })
 }
```

I am trying to add one static value "text", but lets say I have an array of organizations, how can I pre-populate this form?

screen shot of example json format. Here I only need description from both organization(s) and region(s) object(s)

[image]

Comment: Does it work with the static value?

Comment: I am trying to show value in input box in html and it shows.

Comment: Please post the example json file used for populating the form.

Comment: I have updated question with snapshot. I only need description of both organization(s) object and for region object(s)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to add one static value "text", but lets say I have an
> array of organizations, how can I pre-populate this form?
>
> screen shot of example json format. Here I only need description from
> both organization(s) and region(s) object(s)

**TL;DR**
[**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prepopulate-dynamic-reactive-form-array)

---

You need to loop over the data and dynamically call the `buildOrganization` and the `buildRegion` instead of binding data statically.

The methods could be modified like below:~

```
  public createForm() {
    this.service.getOrgData().subscribe(response => {
      this.orgData = response;
      this.editForm = this.fb.group({
        organizations: this.fb.array(
          this.orgData.organisations.map(org => this.buildOrganization(org))
        )
      });
    });
  }

  buildOrganization(org: any) {
    return new FormGroup({
      organizationTitle: new FormControl(org.description),
      regions: this.fb.array(
        org.regions.map(region => this.buildRegion(region))
      )
    });
  }

  buildRegion(region) {
    return new FormGroup({
      regionTitle: new FormControl(region.description)
    });
  }
```

This is the way to **prepopulate a nested dynamic reactive form** with nested form-arrays.

Hope this helps!